# What does Spring Boot test documentation mean？

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

[Spring Boot test documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.mocking-beans) says:

> If your test uses one of Spring Boot’s test annotations (such as
> `@SpringBootTest`), this feature is automatically enabled. To use this
> feature with a different arrangement, listeners must be explicitly
> added...

What does *"To use this feature with a different arrangement, listeners must be explicitly added"* mean？

Comment: Could you clarify what specifically you do and don't understand? _"a different arrangement"_ just means if you're **not** using the Spring Boot test annotations.

Comment: I don`t know when to use these listeners.  what means not using the Spring Boot test annotations. Is that measn using Mockito @Mock instead of SpringBoot @MockBean？

Answer (score 0):

Not using any Spring Boot test annotation means not using `@SpringBootTest` or any other [Spring Boot Test slice annotation](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-test-slices-overview-and-usage/). There are many Spring Boot test annotations that auto-configure the Spring TestContext for you. I can't find a single page that shows them all (there are potentially more added), but the Spring Boot documentation mentions them, [starting from 8.3.12+](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.json-tests).

You can easily identify a Spring Boot test annotation that you put on top of your class by taking a look at the import statement. They all start with `org.springframework.boot.test`, e.g. `@WebMvcTest`, `@DataJpaTest`, `@WebfluxTest`, etc.

Suppose you're not relying on a Spring Boot test annotation and configure your Spring test context manually. In that case, you'll need to add `@TestExecutionListeners({ MockitoTestExecutionListener.class, ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.class })` on top of your test class to use `@MockBean/@SpyBean`.

`@Mock` vs. `@MockBean` is a [different *pitfall*](https://rieckpil.de/difference-between-mock-and-mockbean-spring-boot-applications/). With `@MockBean/@SpyBean` you replace/add beans inside your Spring TestContext, while `@Mock` is for plain unit testing without any Spring TestContext.